# What is the correct way to hyphenate suplicaba? Explain the rule

Tags: ortografía, sustantivos

What is the correct way to hyphenate suplicaba?  Explain the rule.

Comment: Please do add your effort!

Comment: Jerreth, please be more thoughtful when you write your questions. We understand you are here to learn (and many of the users of this site are willing to teach you or help you learn and improve Spanish), but you wrote that question almost as a copy-paste of a exam question, like if you were testing others' knowledge or demanding (quite harshly) an answer. Please, visit the Tour and Help sections, visit other questions to familiarize yourself with the style and rules of this site and try to rewrite your question. Remember we are here to "help you help yourself", not to do homework. Welcome again

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not show any effort on the OP side

Answer (score 2):

The rule is the same for all words in Spanish. You should split by syllables and if you know the pronunciation it is easy.

in this case: su-pli-ca-ba